# How to configure php path for login?

Tags: php, include

I have this php login folder with PHP files that checks and registers and logs in users using a database.

Its all inside a folder called login2 inside my application folder called panini.  So it looks like:

```
serverroot/panini/login2/
```

The app itself, in the `panini/` folder, is simply a php file listing a database table, its an `index.php` file in the panini folder.

Inside the login2 folder, there are a bunch of files including one called `sample_page.php` which looks like this:

```
<?php
//Set permission level threshold for this page remove if page is good for all levels
$permission_level=1;
include"auth_check_header.php";
SUCCESS
?>
```

and if I try to visit `panini/login2/sample_page.php`, I'm redirected to the `login.php` and I'm asked to log in or register.  Once I do, that `sample_page.php` displays the **SUCCESS** word.

So that's great if a file (such as `sample_page.php`) is inside the login2 folder, it works.  But the `index.php` outside the login2 folder, needs the check.  So I added that code snippet above that includes `auth_check_header.php` file.  But I get the error that it can't find `login.php`, because `login.php` is in the login2 folder, not in the panini folder.

How do I configure the app so that it always looks for everything inside the login2 folder?  Or what is the best way to fix this?  Obviously `auth_check_header.php` has an include for `login.php` which I didn't change.  I know I could change it but what if there is a better way, because there may be a lot of includes to deal with individually.  So I'm thinking there's a better way — but what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your problem right you can create a constant with the root of the document and aply it to every link or redirect.

something like

```
define("BASE_URL","/serverroot/");
```

and your links should look like:

```
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>panini/etc.php">ETC</a>
```

so if you decide to host your project you only have to change the constant to the value you need and aply it to every link in your page (always use absolute path for this).

Hope that helps. cheers

Comment: ok the only problem is that i don't have root access to do that. :(  Is there any other solution?

Comment: mmm...have you tried using ´$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']´ ??